# Flutter: Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter

I'm using [Dio Package](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) to send requests to my backend, which send me back the response as Json, but when I try to parse it using jsonDecode I get error saying:

`Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

Here is my code:

```
 Response response = await Dio().post(
              'http://192.168.43.139:8000/api/login',
              data: {"phone": phoneNum, "password": password});

          Map jsonData = jsonDecode(response.data);
          print(jsonData);
```

anyone know how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Try this  `dynamic jsonData = jsonDecode(response.data);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.data);
This will bypass the error.